# How do I link the auto-incremented id from one table to the id in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, auto-increment

I'm currently working on my private messaging system for my website and so far some of what I have to do is making sense.

I've figured I have to use the power of mysql join but have a few questions..
In my model I have started coding for my message inbox and have the following query:

"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_id = '$id'";

$id is basically the auto-incremented id from my users table and from_id is the same thing but in my messages table.

What I want to know is how is the message table suppose to get the from_id? I know that the from_id from the messages table and the auto-incremented id from the users table are what I will use to link both tables.. but I'm slightly stuck how to go about this.

I would rather use id's to identify the sender and receiver of a message than their username but I'm quite confused how to go about setting this up. I'm quite certain I can do it once I have an understanding of it.

Comment: Instead of posting duplicate questions, why not just edit the first one to get better results? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669675/looking-for-tutorial-on-how-to-build-a-private-messaging-system-using-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on what auth library you are using, you will need something like this in CI:

```
view_messages()
{
    //this check could be done in the constructor 
    if($this->auth->logged_in()==TRUE)
    {
        $userID=$this->auth->user_data('userID');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('not_logged_in');
    }

    $this->load->model('message');
    $messages = $this->message->get_messages($userID);
    // do what you want with messages.
    //print_r($messages);
}
```

your  messages model:

```
function get_messages($userID=null)
{
    $this->db->where('userID', $userID);
    $data = $this->db->get('tblMessages');
    return $data->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use session to save the user id when the user login?
That way you can have the user id when needed.

```
// ...

$fromID = $_SESSION['uid'];
INSERT INTO `message` (`from_id`, `to_id`, `time`, `message`) VALUES('$fromID', '$toID', '$time', '$message')
```

Of course, we haven't talk about security here, so the code's obviously not secure. But we'll leave that for another discussion. Have I kicked you in the right direction? :p

Comment: I thought to do that but how does my from_id get a value? where does it come from? I have no problem with grabbing the users id from the session when the user logs in.

Comment: Well, insert in to the database of course. I've just updated my answer. I think it's something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I fully understand you.
You are loading the messages, within the messages table you have a column for the user id but you want to load the users name aswell with a single query?
If so than something like this would do it

> SELECT {whatever you want to have} FROM users
>   u, messages m WHERE u.id=m.from_id

than in your SELECT claus you can retrieve the users details with u.username assuming you have a username column in your users table.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to it than just knowning a little about MySQL joins. There are lots of systems you can download to get a good idea, try phpBB or some other forum software.

With Private Message systems its very easy to make something rubbish, but good ones are tough.

Remember, if your message only has one entry like the example proivided by another user:

```
INSERT INTO `message` (`from_id`, `to_id`, `time`, `message`) VALUES('$fromID', '$toID', '$time', '$message')
```

That will need to show in the Inbox of the to user, and the sent box for the from user. If the to_user deletes it, the from_user suddenly has no record of the message.

You need to create a join table to list all the attachments of users (to or from) joined to the message id. Then you can have multiple to users as well!

Messages should always exist, users just "trash" (set is_trach to 1 on their connection). When users delete from trash they delete only their connection to the message, and when the last user has deleted their connection THEN you can delete it (or get a cron job to delete orphaned messages).