# Looking for tutorial on how to build a private messaging system using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, codeigniter

Looking for tutorial on how to build a secure private messaging system using PHP.

Would be much appreciated.. So far I've been following this one http://www.astahost.com/Private-Message-System-t18247.html

Not really liking the way it's structured though. I would appreciate if anyone could point me to a nice tutorial.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? Encrypted messages? https?

Comment: Just well built.. well ignore the secure part. I'll edit that out because I have a public_controller that allows only logged in users to access specific pages.

Comment: if you don't like the one you're following you can allways change it . don't follow to many tutorials and start developing on you're own ( specialy when you can't find one on you're own , or you don't like the ones you found so far ) . that's the only way you will ever get good at dev .

Comment: Also it should be relative easy to make a private messaging system by your own since login/logout/users/admins part has already been developed. You have to just use database and remember that only sender and receiver should be able to watch that message and the game is done.

Comment: Makes sense now.. not really as complicated as I thought.

Comment: " public_controller that allows only logged in users to access specific pages" ... how does that make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend building your own as then you will be able to build it to the way you like it. I would read some tutorials and then design on paper what you want to build and then build it. You will learn more skills this way and build a better application.

The other side of the coin is what nettuts says:
[Social media website with these 10 code techniques](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/develop-a-social-media-website-with-these-10-code-techniques/)

> The great part about the private messaging feature is that it’s already built-in to many CMS scripts. However, many sites don’t even turn on this feature. Take advantage of this (mostly) pre-built functionality and keep your visitors happy and chatting with each other

It depends on your desired outcomes, are you learning code? Building something you want to work but dont want to reuse the skills?

Comment: This helped quite a lot. I don't know why I didn't think to plan this messaging system out on paper before I built. Things are so much easy right now.